# Error code 422, when I try to retrieve elasticsearch table names in superset

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-superset

I connected superset 3.0.2 to elasticsearch 8.11.1, and the connection is successful.
The problem occurred when I tried add a dataset. The error occurred when superset tried to retrieve table names.
"There was an error loading the tables: Unexpected error occurred please check you logs for details"

Checked the log file. The superset received all the names in json format. With last line `"GET /api/v1/databases/3/tables/?q=(force:!t,schema_name:default) HTTP/1.1" 422`

So I tried SQL labs, when the table names gets loaded the same error occurred.
But I am able to run commands like `SHOW TABLES`, `SELECT * from table`.

Note: No of index is more than 120 and 20 of which in open state.